# Problem with accents in Xperia x10 Mini Pro using CyanogenMod

Tags: cyanogenmod, sony-xperia-x10-mini-pro

When you press and release the button in the bottom-left corner, it normally comes up with smilies and accents. If you hold down on it and press "e" once, it will give you "é".

But with CyanogenMod's mod, it doesn't work. It just does the same as the blue button. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Maybe it might be worth your while to try the latest [LegacyXperia](http://legacyxperia.github.io) to see if it fixes it up? CyanogenMod no longer support those devices, this is where LegacyXperia steps in, to continue the support from where FreeXperia left off, have it running on Xperia Mini, JB ftw.

Answer (score 1):

As far I as I know this feature is available on Stock ROM given by the manufacturer. May be someone might consider this and do a work around to fix this issue on CyanogenMod ROM.

Even this key doesn't work with other soft keyboard applications.